# Modify list so that each element appears twice without changing the order

Tags: python, list

I have been trying for hours. I need to modify a list so that each element only appears twice without changing the order of the list.

I am a beginner and cant think my way around this. All I have thus far is only duplicating the list, but I cant seem to think of how to duplicate the same number only twice to extend the list. What I currently have:

```
def makeDuplicate(my_list):
    new_list = my_list.copy()
    my_list.extend(new_list)
```

But I need(with an example list):

```
my_list = [4, 1 ,2 ,3]
makeDuplicate (my_list)
my_list
```

With the output of:

```
[4 , 1, 2, 3 , 4 , 1 , 2 , 3]
```

Another example:

```
my_list = [4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5]
makeDuplicate(my_list)
my_list
[4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But you are changing the order of the list when you add elements in between others.

Comment: Use a hash table to track how many times an element occurs and append it if doesn't occur more than once already

Comment: How do you get the output in your second example? Please explain further the rules that apply.

Comment: Several objects like list are mutable. In this task, you write a function makeDuplicate(mylist)
that does not return any value, but modifies mylist so that each element appears twice
without changing the order of mylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
my_first_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_second_list = [4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
def makeDuplicate(my_list):
    my_list += my_list
    my_list.reverse()
    for i in my_list:
        if my_list.count(i) > 2:
            my_list.remove(i)
    my_list.reverse()
    return my_list


print(makeDuplicate(my_first_list))
print(makeDuplicate(my_second_list))
```

it's not beautiful code but works ;)

Comment: Thank you, this works! I was thinking about the algorithm of something like this, but couldnt wrap my head around this. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_list = [4 ,1 ,2 ,3]
>>> my_list * 2
[4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Edit: I am updating my answer after the comment below and the second example

```
my_list = [4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5] 
frequency = {}
for elem in my_list:          
    if elem in frequency:     
        frequency [elem] += 1 
    else:                     
        frequency [elem] = 1  

items_to_append = []
for elem in my_list:                 
    if frequency [elem] == 1:        
        items_to_append.append (elem)
my_list.extend (items_to_append)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a brutal force way to do it.

First, you simple duplicated the list and extend it to the original list, just like what you have done here.

However, this would not guarantee that the numbers in the list appears exactly twice. So you can simply go through the extended list and count the number of times that each distinct value appears. If a value has already shown twice, then you delete this value next time you encounter it in the list.
To count the number of times a distinct value appears, you can use dictionary to count it.

Original: my_list = [4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5]

Extend: my_list = [4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5, 4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5]

Delete: my_list = [4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5]

Comment: How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this step by step approach:

```
data=[4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5]


def copy_list(list_):
    #create a copy 
    copy_=list_[:]
    copy_.extend(list_)

    # save the index of each no for tracking

    hash_table={}
    for i,j in enumerate(copy_):
        if j not in hash_table:
            hash_table[j]=[(i,j)]
        else:
            hash_table[j].append((i,j))


    #check if a no is there more than 2 times 


    for ma,mm in hash_table.items():

        if len(mm)>2:
            hash_table[ma]=mm[:2]
    n=hash_table.values()
    datay=[0]*int(max([m[0] for i in n for m in i])+1)


    # save no as previous index without changing their order


    for ii,jj in hash_table.items():
        for mm in jj:
            datay[mm[0]]=mm[1]

    #just filter result 


    return list(filter(None,datay))

print(copy_list(data))
```

output:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5]
```